# Python discord bot Random number generator

Tags: python, random, discord

I wanted to make a random number generator, which picks a random number from a list...
I came up with this but everytime I run it its 0 and I dont know where the problem is...
Thanks for helping :>

```
     async def on_message(self, message):
        seed(1)
        sequence = [i for i in range(2)]
        print(sequence)
        if message.content.startswith("test"):
            for _ in range(1):
                value = choice(sequence)

                if value == 0:
                    await message.channel.send("0")

                if value == 1:
                    await message.channel.send("1")
```

Comment: A constant number for a RNG seed is always going to produce the same results. Perhaps you should consider having a dynamic number for your seed value, like maybe `int(time.time())`?

Comment: what should i replace?

Comment: In this case, it would be the argument you're providing to your call of `seed()`. Because that's a number that will be the same every time, you will always receive the same output. If your seed changes each time you run the function, then you will start to receive different results. Time is a commonly used seed. Just remember, with two choice, you may end up getting the same result a number of times. Improbable, but not without possibility.

Answer (score 0):

cant you do this instead.

```py
import random

async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith("test"):
        await message.channel.send(str(choice([0,1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just understang the use of Random Library and apply it to your project

```
import random 
def showing_you_the_use_of_random_function():
    random_value = random.choice(range(0,2))
    return random_value
    
print(showing_you_the_use_of_random_function())
```

Comment: it now just outputs 1

Comment: run again and again it will output 0 too...its random that's why..just copy my code as it is and run it in some compiler again and again.... maybe for 15 times...it will hardly takes 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

OK everything works fine, if u use the solution from user3832673... just setting the seed to the time :
seed(int(time.time()))